# How can I use Unicode characters on the Windows command line?

Tags: unicode, command-line, input, windows-console

We have a project in [Team Foundation Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azure_DevOps_Server) (TFS) that has a non-English character (š) in it. When trying to script a few build-related things, we've stumbled upon a problem; we can't pass the **š** letter to the command-line tools. The command prompt or what not else messes it up, and the **tf.exe** utility can't find the specified project.

I've tried different formats for the .bat file (ANSI, [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) with and without [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)) as well as scripting it in JavaScript (which is Unicode inherently), but no luck. How do I execute a program and pass it a **Unicode** command line?

Comment: Python 3.6: "the default console on Windows accept all Unicode characters with that version" (well, most of it for me) **BUT** you need to configure the console: right click on the top of the windows (of the cmd or the python IDLE), in default/font choose the "Lucida console".

Comment: [Output unicode strings in Windows console app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2492077/995714), [Output Unicode to console Using C++, in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2849010/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Output Unicode Strings on the Windows Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130979/how-to-output-unicode-strings-on-the-windows-console)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc - No, this is about passing unicode command line arguments, rather than displaying text in the console. Console might not get involved at all.

Comment: Related.
• [What encoding to get Å Ä Ö to work](https://superuser.com/q/675369)
• [Using UTF-8 Encoding (CHCP 65001) in Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57131654)
• [How to use unicode characters in Windows command line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388490)
• [chcp 65001 and a .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32182619)
• [Making Swedish characters show properly in Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2660264)

Comment: Question's about i/o (keyboard/screen/program) which usually works ok in modern consoles like Win10--HOWEVER the font rendering the character is another matter: If you see "squares" or placeholders, the selected font might be to blame; with default Win10, try using the NSimSun font via console menu->properties. It should get the glyph to print properly. This may be technically off topic but some might find their way here like I did-hope that helps.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

My background: I have used Unicode input/output in a console for years (and do it a lot daily. Moreover, I develop support tools for exactly this task). There are very few problems, as far as you understand the following facts/limitations:

- `CMD` and “console” are unrelated factors.  `CMD.exe` is a just one of programs which are ready to “work inside” a console (“console applications”).
- AFAIK, `CMD` has perfect support for Unicode; you can enter/output all Unicode chars when *any* [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) is active.
- Windows’ console has *a lot* of support for Unicode — but it is not perfect (just “good enough”; see below).
- `chcp 65001` is very dangerous.  Unless a program was specially designed to work around defects in the Windows’ API (or uses a C runtime library which has these workarounds), it would not work reliably.  [Windows 8 fixes ½ of these problems with `cp65001`, but the rest is still applicable to Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39745938/9106292).
- I work in *[Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252)*.  As I already said: **To input/output Unicode in a console, one does not need to set the code page**.

## The details

- To read/write Unicode to a console, an application (or its C runtime library) should be smart enough to use not the `File-I/O` API, but the `Console-I/O` API.  (For an example, see [how Python does it](https://peps.python.org/pep-0528/).)
- Likewise, to read Unicode command-line arguments, an application (or its C runtime library) should be smart enough to use the corresponding API.
- Console font rendering supports only Unicode characters in [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_%28Unicode%29) (in other words: below `U+10000`).  Only simple text rendering is supported (so European — and some East Asian — languages should work fine — as far as one uses precomposed forms).  [There is a [minor] fine print](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852866/9106292) here for East Asian and for characters U+0000, U+0001, U+30FB.]

## Practical considerations

- The **defaults** on Window are not very helpful.  For best experience, one should tune up three pieces of configuration:

  - For output: a comprehensive console font.  For best results, I recommend [my builds](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eserganov/ilyaz.org/software/fonts/).  (The installation instructions are present there — and also listed in other answers on this page.)
  - For input: a capable keyboard layout.  For best results, I recommend [my layouts](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Eserganov/ilyaz.org/keyboard/).
  - For input: [allow hexadecimal input of Unicode](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&pws=0&q=enable-hex-unicode-entry%20windows%20registry).
- One more gotcha with “Pasting” into a console application (very technical):

  - Hexadecimal input delivers a character on *KeyUp* of <kbd>Alt</kbd>; *all* the other ways to deliver a character happen on *KeyDown*; so many applications are not ready to see a character on *KeyUp*.  (Only applicable to applications using the *Console-I/O* API.)
  - Conclusion: many applications would not react on hexadecimal input events.
  - Moreover, what happens with a “Pasted” character depends on the current keyboard layout: if the character can be typed without using prefix keys (but with arbitrary complicated combination of modifiers, as in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>Kana</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Gray</kbd>) then it is delivered on an emulated key press.  This is what any application expects — so pasting anything which contains only such characters is fine.
  - However, the “other” characters are delivered by **emulating hexadecimal input**.

  ***Conclusion***: unless your keyboard layout supports input of *a lot* of characters without prefix keys, *some buggy applications* may skip characters when you `Paste` via Console’s UI: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.  (**This** is why I recommend using my keyboard layouts!)

One should also keep in mind that the “alternative, ‘more capable’ consoles” for Windows **are not consoles at all**.  They do not support *Console-I/O* APIs, so the programs which rely on these APIs to work would not function.  (The programs which use only “File-I/O APIs to the console file handles” would work fine, though.)

One example of such non-console is a part of Microsoft’s [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell).  I do not use it; to experiment, press and release the <kbd>[Windows key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_key)</kbd>, and then type `powershell`.

---

(On the other hand, there are programs such as *[ConEmu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConEmu)* or *[ANSICON](http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/)* which try to do more: they “attempt” to intercept the *Console-I/O* APIs to make “true console applications” work too.  This definitely works for toy example programs; in real life, this may or may not solve your particular problems.  Experiment.)

## Summary

- set font, keyboard layout (and optionally, allow hexadecimal input).
- use only programs which go through the *Console-I/O* APIs, and accept Unicode command-line arguments.  For example, any [Cygwin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cygwin)-compiled program should be fine.  As I already said, [CMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) is fine too.

***Update:*** Initially, for a bug in `cp65001`, I was mixing up Kernel and CRTL layers (***Update 2:*** and Windows user-mode API!).  *Also:* Windows 8 fixes one half of this bug; I clarified the section about “better console” application, and added a reference to how Python does it.

Answer (score 438):

Try:

```
chcp 65001
```

which will change the code page to UTF-8. Also, you need to use Lucida console fonts.

Comment: Note there are serious implementation bugs in Windows's code page 65001 support which will break many applications that rely on the C standard library IO methods, so this is very fragile. (Batch files also just stop working in 65001.) Unfortunately UTF-8 is a second-class citizen in Windows.

Comment: @bobince Do you have an example of a bug in the Windows code page 65001 support? I'm curious because I've never run into one, and googling didn't turn anything up either. (Batch files do stop working, of course, but UTF-8 is hardly a second-class citizen...)

Comment: @romkyns: My understanding is that calls that return a number-of-bytes (such as fread/fwrite/etc) actually return a number-of-characters. This causes a wide variety of symptoms, such as incomplete input-reading, hangs in fflush, the broken batch files and so on. [Some background.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e4b91f49-6f60-4ffe-887a-e18e39250905/) The default code pages used for CJK "multibyte" locales have special handling built in to fix this, but 65001 doesn't - it is [not supported](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2006/03/13/550191.aspx).

Comment: Updated Kaplan blog on broken UTF-8 in windows [available here](http://www.siao2.com/2006/03/13/550191.aspx), since Microsoft deleted all his blog posts after he rubbed a higher-up the wrong way.

Comment: To make utf-8 the default encoding: go to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun]` and set it to `chcp 65001`

Comment: The console's  (conhost.exe) support for codepage 65001 is fundamentally broken (for both input and output in Windows 7, but still broken for input in Windows 10). Please remove this suggestion to avoid repeating this bad advice in an endless loop of naive 'help'. The cmd shell is a Unicode application that uses the console's UTF-16 API and base APIs `CreateProcessW` and `ShellExecuteExW`. If there's a problem with handling the command-line, it's because the application is using the ANSI encoded `char *` version from a standard C `main` instead of the `wchar_t *` from a `wmain` entry point.

Comment: **–1** UTF-8 in consoles works only partially and only for output. Additionally the question isn't about i/o but about command line arguments.

Comment: This just don't work and is useless nearly completely. At the end you must use ReadConsoleW / WriteConsoleW by your self and translate from/to UTF-16 for can have proper UTF-8 input / output. Turns out that Windows must be used with UTF-16 for have full Unicode support. For output there exists libfmt which internally uses WriteConsoleW, for input you can use the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1660492/utf-8-output-on-windows-console

Comment: [`SetConsoleOutputCP(65001)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoleoutputcp) seems to work.

Answer (score 42):

I had same problem (I'm from the Czech Republic). I have an English installation of Windows, and I have to work with files on a shared drive. Paths to the files include Czech-specific characters.

The solution that works for me is:

In the batch file, change the charset page

My batch file:

```
chcp 1250
copy "O:\VEŘEJNÉ\ŽŽŽŽŽŽ\Ž.xls" c:\temp
```

The batch file has to be saved in CP 1250.

Note that the console will not show characters correctly, but it will understand them...

Answer (score 33):

Check the language for non-Unicode programs. If you have problems with Russian in the Windows console, then you should set Russian here:

[image: Changing language for non-Unicode programs]

Comment: That doesn't enable support for Unicode in `cmd`, it only switches the default codepage to `cp866` which is still an 8-bit character set. It even uses `cp866` instead of `cp1251` which adds its own shitload of trouble.

Answer (score 16):

It's is quite difficult to change the default Codepage of Windows console. When you search the web you find different proposals, however some of them may break your Windows entirely, i.e. your PC does not boot anymore.

The most secure solution is this one:
Go to your Registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and add String value `Autorun` = `chcp 65001`.

Or you can use this small Batch-Script for the most common code pages.

```
@ECHO off

SET ROOT_KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER"


FOR /f "skip=2 tokens=3" %%i in ('reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Nls\CodePage /v OEMCP') do set OEMCP=%%i

ECHO System default values:

ECHO.
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO Select Codepage 
ECHO ...............................................
ECHO.
ECHO 1 - CP1252
ECHO 2 - UTF-8
ECHO 3 - CP850
ECHO 4 - ISO-8859-1
ECHO 5 - ISO-8859-15
ECHO 6 - US-ASCII
ECHO.
ECHO 9 - Reset to System Default (CP%OEMCP%)
ECHO 0 - EXIT
ECHO.


SET /P  CP="Select a Codepage: "

if %CP%==1 (
    echo Set default Codepage to CP1252
    reg add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 1252>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==2 (
    echo Set default Codepage to UTF-8
    reg add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 65001>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==3 (
    echo Set default Codepage to CP850
    reg add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 850>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==4 (
    echo Set default Codepage to ISO-8859-1
    add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 28591>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==5 (
    echo Set default Codepage to ISO-8859-15
    add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 28605>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==6 (
    echo Set default Codepage to ASCII
    add "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v Autorun /t REG_SZ /d "@chcp 20127>nul" /f
) else if %CP%==9 (
    echo Reset Codepage to System Default
    reg delete "%ROOT_KEY%\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" /v AutoRun /f
) else if %CP%==0 (
    echo Bye
) else (
    echo Invalid choice
    pause
)
```

Using `@chcp 65001>nul` instead of `chcp 65001` suppresses the output "Active code page: 65001" you would get every time you start a new command line windows.

A full list of all available number you can get from [Code Page Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Note, the settings will apply only for the current user. If you like to set it for all users, replace line `SET ROOT_KEY="HKEY_CURRENT_USER"` by `SET ROOT_KEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE"`

Answer (score 16):

On a Windows 10 x64 machine, I made the command prompt display non-English characters by:

Open an elevated command prompt (run CMD.EXE as administrator). Query your registry for available TrueType fonts to the console by:

```
    REG query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont"
```

You'll see an output like:

```
    0    REG_SZ    Lucida Console
    00    REG_SZ    Consolas
    936    REG_SZ    *新宋体
    932    REG_SZ    *ＭＳ ゴシック
```

Now we need to add a TrueType font that supports the characters you need like Courier New. We do this by adding zeros to the string name, so in this case the next one would be "000":

```
    REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont" /v 000 /t REG_SZ /d "Courier New"
```

Now we implement UTF-8 support:

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Console /v CodePage /t REG_DWORD /d 65001 /f
```

Set default font to "Courier New":

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Console /v FaceName /t REG_SZ /d "Courier New" /f
```

Set font size to 20:

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Console /v FontSize /t REG_DWORD /d 20 /f
```

Enable quick edit if you like:

```
    REG ADD HKCU\Console /v QuickEdit /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: In general using codepage 65001 will only work without bugs in Windows 10 with the Creators update. In Windows 7 it will have both output and input bugs. In Windows 8 and older versions of Windows 10 it only has the input bug, which limits input to 7-bit ASCII.

Comment: I tried using this method, and now the font is super small and it seem it is permanent.

Answer (score 14):

Actually, the trick is that the command prompt actually understands these non-English characters, just can't display them correctly.

When I enter a path in the command prompt that contains some non-English characters it is displayed as "?? ?????? ?????". When you submit your command (cd "??? ?????? ?????" in my case), everything is working as expected.

Answer (score 10):

One really simple option is to install a Windows bash shell such as [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/) and use that:

[image]

There is a little bit of a learning curve as you will need to use Unix command line functionality, but you will love the power of it and you can set the console character set to UTF-8.

[image]

Of course you also get all the usual *nix goodies like grep, find, less, etc.

Answer (score 10):

I found this method as useful in new versions of Windows 10:

Turn on this feature: "Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support"

> Control panel ->  Regional settings -> Administrative tab-> Change
>   system locale...

[image: Region Settings]

Comment: Just be careful with this, it broke the functionality of some old and crappy programs that were working fine in server 2019.

Answer (score 8):

Starting June 2019, with Windows 10, you won't have to change the codepage.

See "[Introducing Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal/)" (from [**Kayla Cinnamon**](https://twitter.com/cinnamon_msft)) and the [**Microsoft/Terminal**](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal).
Through the use of the Consolas font, *partial* Unicode support will be provided.

As documented in [`Microsoft/Terminal` issue 387](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal/issues/387#issuecomment-471926057):

> There are 87,887 ideographs currently in Unicode. You need all of them too?
>   We need a boundary, and characters beyond that boundary should be handled by font fallback / font linking / whatever.
>
> What Consolas should cover:
>
> - Characters that used as symbols that used by modern OSS programs in CLI.
> - These characters should follow Consolas' design and metrics, and properly aligned with existing Consolas characters.
>
> What Consolas should NOT cover:
>
> - Characters and punctuation of scripts that beyond Latin, Greek and Cyrillic, especially characters need complex shaping (like Arabic).
> - These characters should be handled with font fallback.

Comment: Note that Windows terminal may not be installed / used by default, more information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/install). I strongly recommend using it of course, anything is better than the old command line.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes True. I only use Windows Terminal these days.

Answer (score 6):

As I haven't seen any full answers for Python 2.7, I'll outline the two important steps and an optional step that is quite useful.

1. You need a font with Unicode support. Windows comes with Lucida Console which may be selected by **right-clicking the title bar** of command prompt and clicking the `Defaults` option. This also gives access to colours. Note that you can also change settings for command windows invoked in certain ways (e.g, open here, Visual Studio) by choosing `Properties` instead.
2. You need to set the code page to `cp65001`, which appears to be Microsoft's attempt to offer UTF-7 and UTF-8 support to command prompt. Do this by running **`chcp 65001` in command prompt**. Once set, it remains this way until the window is closed. You'll need to redo this every time you launch cmd.exe.

For a more permanent solution, refer to [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/269857/576775) on Super User. In short, create a `REG_SZ` (String) entry using regedit at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor` and name it `AutoRun`. Change the value of it to `chcp 65001`. If you don't want to see the output message from the command, use `@chcp 65001>nul` instead.

Some programs have trouble interacting with this encoding, MinGW being a notable one that fails while compiling with a nonsensical error message. Nonetheless, this works very well and doesn't cause bugs with the majority of programs.

Answer (score 5):

This problem is quite annoying. I usually have Chinese character in my filename and file content. Please note that I am using Windows 10, here is my solution:

To display the **file name**, such as `dir` or `ls` if you installed Ubuntu bash on Windows 10

1. Set the region to support non-utf 8 character.
2. After that, console's font will be changed to the font of that locale, and it also changes the encoding of the console.

After you have done previous steps, in order to display the **file content** of a UTF-8 file using command line tool

1. Change the page to utf-8 by `chcp 65001`
2. Change to the font that supports utf-8, such as Lucida Console
3. Use `type` command to peek the file content, or `cat` if you installed Ubuntu bash on Windows 10
4. Please note that, after setting the encoding of the console to utf-8, I can't type Chinese character in the cmd using Chinese input method.

The laziest solution: Just use a console emulator such as http://cmder.net/

Answer (score 3):

For a similar problem, (my problem was to show UTF-8 characters from MySQL on a command prompt),

I solved it like this:

1. I changed the font of command prompt to Lucida Console. (This step must be irrelevant for your situation. It has to do only with what you see on the screen and not with what is really the character).
2. I changed the codepage to Windows-1253. You do this on the command prompt by "chcp 1253". It worked for my case where I wanted to see UTF-8.

Comment: Windws-1253 isn't an Unicode codepage. It's a standard 256-character codepage. Apparently you only used characters that can be displayed in that codepage, but it won't be universal.

Answer (score 3):

A quick decision for .bat files if you computer displays your path/file name correct when you typing it in DOS-window:

1. ***copy con temp.txt*** [press Enter]
2. Type the path/file name [press Enter]
3. Press ***Ctrl-Z*** [press Enter]

This way you create a .txt file - temp.txt. Open it in Notepad, copy the text (don't worry it will look unreadable) and paste it in your .bat file.
Executing the .bat created this way in DOS-window worked for mе (Cyrillic, Bulgarian).

Answer (score 3):

I see several answers here, but they don't seem to address the question—the user wants to get Unicode input from the command line.

Windows uses [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for encoding in two byte strings, so you need to get these from the OS in your program.  There are two ways to do this—

1. Microsoft has an extension that allows *[main](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entry_point#C_and_C++)* to take a wide character array:
   int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[]);
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6wd819wh.aspx
2. Call the Windows API to get the Unicode version of the command line
   wchar_t **win_argv = (wchar_t**)CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLineW(), &nargs);
   *[CommandLineToArgvW function (shellapi.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw)*

Read *[UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org)* for detailed information, particularly if you are supporting other operating systems.

Comment: Ahh, no, I'm sorry, but you missed the question. This is for when I'm writing a program that will **receive** the unicode characters. My question was about **sending** the unicode characters to another program (which hopefully supports receiving them, but I really have no way to know except disassembly).

Answer (score 2):

A better cleaner thing to do: Just install the available, free, Microsoft Japanese language pack. (Other oriental language packs will also work, but I have tested the Japanese one.)

This gives you the fonts with the larger sets of glyphs, makes them the default behavior, changes the various Windows tools like cmd, WordPad, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Changing code page to 1252 is working for me. The problem for me is the symbol double doller § is converting to another symbol by DOS on Windows Server 2008.

I have used CHCP 1252 and a cap before it in my BCP statement ^§.

Answer (score 1):

I got around a similar issue deleting Unicode-named files by referring to them in the batch file by their short (8 dot 3) names.

The short names can be viewed by doing `dir /x`. Obviously, this only works with Unicode file names that are already known.

Answer (score 0):

Mind for those using [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) who also do not want the extra packages from Cygwin or Git,  [wsltty](https://github.com/mintty/wsltty/releases) is available which provides just the terminal with UTF-8 support.